# Pagination to deal with lots of posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a standard CRUD forum with posts and comments.

Currently the index page displays all posts, I would like to have it display the last 10 posts with links to the next page of 10 etc. like at the bottom of a google search. like this:

<<  1 2 3 4 5 6  >>

It seems like something fairly common, how do people usually approach this? Is there a common git, or do people usually just code it by hand?

Comment: First stop for a great overview of available gems / plugins for Ruby and Rails: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Here's a [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) to help you

**EDIT:**

There is another gem for pagination : [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari))

Comment: I noticed while watching the railscast, he installed with script leading me to believe will_paginate is a gem for 2.3, will it work in 3 or should i look for something else?

Comment: nevermind, the next rails cast you noted (kaminari) answers that question

Comment: Kaminari is more complete than will_paginate. Nevertheless, will_paginate also works for rails 3.

Answer (score 3):

Look at these gems:

- https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate
- https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: +1 for kaminari. Seems the better / cleaner way to go nowadays.

Comment: thank-you guys, I would have had an easier time searching if I knew the term for what I'm trying to do was "paginate"